get url in Chrome Custom Tabs
I want to get the URL in Chrome Custom Tabs, and I wrote the code according to the demo.I set up the button according to this code, but after clicking, the obtained URL is null. Has anyone succeeded? Thank you very much.
I reproduced the code once.But it didn't work. My chrome version is 126.0.6478.71 on Android 14

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
